# Wordpress multiple shortcodes on same page doesn't keep element ordering

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin that creates shortcodes. Even though the shortcodes parse as they should, I have a problem when using multiple shortcodes on the same page. So, if I do it like this in post editor:

```
[foobar]
<p>Lorem ipsum text</p>
[foobar]
<p>Some other text</p>
[foobar]
```

the HTML output is:

```
<div class="foobar">Foobar</div>
<div class="foobar">Foobar</div>
<div class="foobar">Foobar</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum text</p>
<p>Some other text</p>
```

So, it places all the shortcodes one after another, and then displays the rest of the text on page. Instead, I'd like to have that as I wrote it in post editor.

Comment: you not created shortcodes in right way

Comment: Mind telling me what do you think it's wrong?

Comment: What do you exactly want to implement?

Comment: I told you, to keep order, so, I want to add text, then shortcode, then other text, then same shortcode, then third paragraph. When I do that in wp content editor, it parses all the shortcodes first, then adds all the text, no matter how I place them in editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you are echo'ing the values, instead of returning them.

So, instead of doing

'echo "something" '

Do

' return "something" '

Answer (score 0):

this the correct way to define the shortcode

```
[foobar]
Lorem ipsum text
[/foobar]
[foobar]
Some other text
[/foobar]
```

Comment: Nope, that's when you want to change text in between shortcodes. My syntax is right.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was using echo instead of return.